# Newtonian mechanics. If I'm inside a wagon and I pull a spring connected to the wall, will the wagon move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Suppose the mass of the wagon is very small. 
There's a spring connected to the wall inside the wagon. If I pull the spring, does the wagon move?

Comment: Why would you think it wouldn’t?

Comment: well. i thought i should push the floor of the wagon to pull the string so it wouldn't move

Comment: Floor of the wagon or under the wago?

Comment: the floor of the wagon. push the floor of the wagon to pull the string

Comment: Removed a few answers to the question posted as comments.

Answer (score 1):

In closed system, the momentum of centre of mass remains the same due to the law of conservation of momentum. Since you are inside the wagon, anything you do won't influence the movement of centre of mass of you+string+wagon system.

If the string is connected to the right wall and you pull it to the left, you are changing the distribution of mass inside the wagon, so the wagon will move to the right to keep the centre of mass still.

But no more

Answer (score 0):

Newton's third law is: For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.

If you pull on the string the wagon pulls back. Presumably, you grip the floor with your feet to prevent yourself from moving. The wagon grips your feet with the floor to prevent itself from moving.

If you stop gripping, you and the wagon will pull yourselves together. The amount you and the wagon move will depend on your relative masses.

What happens next depends on whether you fall off the wagon or not. If you fall off, you and the wagon will continue in opposite directions. Your total momentum will be zero though.

If you grip your feet again to stop moving you will need to push against the floor of the wagon to stop your movement. The floor of the wagon pushes against your feet and that stops its movement.

In reality, there could be friction and things and you may be able to bounce the wagon along somehow (as any kid with a trike knows), but other than that you can't move the wagon *and* stay on it by pulling or pushing the body of the wagon. You can try turning the wheels of course!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the wagon and the wall is in the wagon, how are you going to be able to move the wagon? I.e it will not move. On the contrary if the wall is outside the wagon then you are applying a force on the wagon floor with your feet and the wagon will move.

Answer (score -1):

Take the system of wagon and yourself. The tension in the string is an internal force. The wagon would not move unless an external force acts on it